# Css is not executing in Browser

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm new at MVCApplication development. I'm working in Visual Studio 2012 on a local server. I have two views: Index and Puppies. When the request is generated for Index, the Browser loads and execute CSS. However, when the request is generated for Puppies, the Browser don't execute CSS. Can someone help me figure out why?

Here is my Controller Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace EAD_PROJECT_MVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {            
            return View();
        }

        public ViewResult Puppies()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Layout page _header_footer.cshtml

```
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Header_footer";
}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>PetZone</title>
        <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="Custom_Scripts/index_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type/="text/css"/>
        <link href="Custom_Scripts/puppies_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>

<body>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-tab" role="navigation">

        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar-tab-list"> 
                <li class="item active"> <a href="#" id="list-item-1"  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("index")'"> <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home </a></li>               
                <li class="item active"> <a href="#" id="list-item-2"  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("puppies")'">  Puppies </a></li>               

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Here is my Index

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/_header_footer.cshtml";    
}

<h2>index</h2>
```

Here is my Puppies.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/_header_footer.cshtml";    
}

<h2>puppies</h2>
```

Comment: _Guide me What is happening._ Imperative sentences will just give you downvotes. Watch your tone.

Comment: just a view containing a head. given in the end.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, basically it's my first Question here, So that's why this happens. Next time i will take much care of my Words.

Comment: @HAMADMAHMOOD: Please try this: Drag your "style sheet" from your solution explorer and place it into your 'head' tag for me.

Comment: @jbutler Actually I have reduced my example to be precise, the code was a large bit, but the issue is resolved. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your layout page style links look wrong:

```
<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Should need to be as follows to work for 'puppies':

```
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

If your home page (index) url is, e.g.:

www.something.com (relative links work from this point)

and puppies is:

www.something.com/home/puppies (relative links are now all broken)

then this would explain what is happening.

Your links should be set to be relative to the page they render on, by writing them like so:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You should also get to know the developer bar in your browser - the network access tab is great for figuring out what is not loading.

Comment: you can also drag and drop them from the solution explorer (does this for you)

Comment: Now facing the same problem for images, How to figure it out?

Comment: Use relative paths to the images along your CSS rules (in the stylesheets).

Comment: Thank you, Your solution work for both CSS and Images.